# C++ linux interface for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I know Cygwin is a Windows interface for Linux, but is there a Linux interface for windows.

If I use a Linux interface for Windows, once a library is built on this interface can it be used to build projects on Windows?

I'm looking for a solution to the myriad of build errors I get when building open source C++ Libraries.

Thanks

Comment: You can look at https://www.reactos.org. It's an open-source implementation of the Windows platform. You can use their headers and libraries with a Linux-hosted cross-compiler that targets Windows, and test your binaries using Wine. No promises as to whether it'll work for your particular application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin is not a "Windows interface for Linux" per se. It's a set of emulation libraries, tools, and bash shell that allows for existing Unix/Linux code to be recompiled and run on Windows. Apps compiled as EXEs within Cygwin can usually be redistributed to other Windows machines simply by including the built EXE and some subset of Cygwin DLLs into the same install directory.

I suspect if you took the open source code, and built as a shared libary (.dll) under Cygwin, you could link your code to that DLL. Might be possible to build .lib files, but I've never tried. Then distribute your executables built under Visual Studio (or other compiler), the Cygwin compiled binaries, and the Cygwin runtime together.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  That's a pretty good explanation of Cygwin.   I'm beginning to wonder if there's anything out there these moderators haven't put on hold.  Stackoverflow seems to be leaning away from being a true forum to being and over policed website.     Thanks again for your help, I'll look into this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @domonica. Your question was likely put on hold for the following reasons: 1. Was asking for general help to an ambiguous problem of getting your code to compile.  *"'Im looking for a solution to the myriad of build errors..."* is not specific enough.

2. Your title to your question didn't match what you were really asking. Instead of saying *"C++ linux interface for Windows"*, you could have titled it **"Trouble porting code from Linux to Windows"**, and then mentioned if Cygwin was an option within the question as a solution in the broader sense.

Comment: Imagine if your question was worded like this: "I'm attempting to include the source files of libWhatever into my Windows Visual Studio project. The trouble is that I get a lot of build errors such as the following: <show output>   How do I workaround these types of errors?  Or should I take a different approach getting this code normally meant for Linux to compile and work for Windows? I've heard about Cygwin - would that help?*"

Comment: Andrew got it first go.  You are just nit picking for the sake of moderating.  I didn't ask for technical help, just a broad answer for a broad question.  Someone else will benefit from this.

Comment: @domonica - ??? I'm way confused on why you keep calling me Andrew. I'm the guy (selbie) who actually answered your question. :) Andrew just edited my answer because I misspelled something.  Everyone else just voted your question down and closed it.  I'm not only providing you and answer to your question, I'm also attempting trying to inform you on the [StackOverflow guidelines of what questions are discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  And yes, [seeking broad answers to broad questions is discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: This is a good read as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: aha.. So it is, Selbie.. Sorry about that. It was a good question and it cleared some confusion up for me.